# How to combine numeric columns in pandas dataframe with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this format:

```
ID measurement_1 measurement_2
0      3              NaN
1      NaN            5
2      NaN            7 
3      NaN            NaN
```

I want to combine to:

```
ID measurement measurement_type
0      3              1
1      5              2
2      7              2
```

For each row there will be a value in either `measurement_1` or `measurement_2` column, not in both, the other column will be NaN.
In some rows both columns will be NaN.

I want to add a column for the measurement type (depending on which column has the value) and take the actual value out of both columns, and remove the rows that have NaN in both columns.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a sample output?

Comment: the sample output is the 2nd dataframe shown

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the dataframe then use `reset_index` and use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to assign the column `measurement_type` by using `Series.str.split` + `Series.str[:1]` on `level_1`:

```
df1 = (
    df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(name='measurement')
    .assign(mesurement_type=lambda x: x.pop('level_1').str.split('_').str[-1])
)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
   ID  measurement mesurement_type
0   0          3.0               1
1   1          5.0               2
2   2          7.0               2
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) could help?

```
import numpy as np


df["measurement"] = df["measurement_1"].combine_first(df["measurement_2"])
df["measurement_type"] = np.where(df["measurement_1"].notnull(), 1, 2)
df.drop(["measurement_1", "measurement_2"], 1)
```

---

```
    ID  measurement measurement_type
0   0   3           1
1   1   5           2
2   2   7           2
```

Answer (score 5):

Set a threshold and drop any that has more than one `NaN`. Use `df.assign` to `fillna()` measurement_1 and apply `np.where` on measurement_2

```
  df= df.dropna(thresh=2).assign(measurement=df.measurement_1.fillna\
                             (df.measurement_2), measurement_type=np.where(df.measurement_2.isna(),1,2)).drop(columns=['measurement_1','measurement_2'])

    ID  measurement  measurement_type
0   0              3              1
1   1              5              2
2   2              7              2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [pandas melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) :

```
(
    df.melt("ID", var_name="measurement_type", value_name="measurement")
    .dropna()
    .assign(measurement_type=lambda x: x.measurement_type.str[-1])
    .iloc[:, [0, -1, 1]]
    .astype("int8")
)
```

or [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) :

```
(
    pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames="measurement", i="ID", 
                    j="measurement_type", sep="_")
    .dropna()
    .reset_index()
    .astype("int8")
    .iloc[:, [0, -1, 1]]
)



    ID  measurement measurement_type
0   0          3        1
1   1          5        2
2   2          7        2
```